# opening and copy/pasting variable named file

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following vba code which opens a Folder, where i save the Excel files with certain names ("11.xlsm and "2.xlsm") and then open These files automatically and copy their Sheets called "data" and paste it to my masterworkbook "makrotochange".

```
 ChDir _
    "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\11.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\2.xlsm"
Windows("makrotochange.xlsm").Activate



 Windows("11.xlsm").Activate
sheets("data").Select

sheets("data").Move After:=Workbooks("makrotochange.xlsm").sheets(23)

Windows("2.xlsm").Activate

sheets("data").Select
sheets("data").Move After:=Workbooks("makrotochange.xlsm").sheets(24)
```

I want to be able to open any amount of variable named files which is in

```
"Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA"
```

and copy/paste it to my "makrotochange.xlsm" masterworkbook.

How can i do this ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Comment: doesnt help me at all, thanks though !

Comment: Actually, i think that link will help you more than you think. The link shows code that will open all files in a folder if they have the word test in the name. If you replace the "IF" statement in the middle of the loop with your copy/paste code, you will have the code to loop through every file in a folder, copy from it, paste to another, and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, as i am currently unable to use Excel. However, using the information you provided, and the link @Mrig provided, i believe this could be the base for what you're looking for.

```
    Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim StrFile As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim InputFilePath As String
InputFilePath = "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\"
StrFile = Dir(InputFilePath & "*")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath & StrFile)
        WB.Activate
            Sheets("data").Select
            Sheets("data").Move After:=Workbooks("makrotochange.xlsm").Sheets(23)
            StrFile = Dir()
    Loop
    End Sub
```

EDITED

Edited the code now that i am able to use Excel.

This will take all the files in the folder, open them, copy the "Data" sheet, and move it to after sheet 23 in your makrotochange.xlsm file.

A few points of interest though.
You need to make sure that your makrotochange.xlsm file is open to begin with. 
You need to make sure all files have a sheet called "Data".
They will be pasted after Sheet 23. So the last file to be pasted in will be the one next to sheet 23.

Have fun

Comment: thank you for the help. However this does not compile, as it states Workbooks.Close (False) causes Problem. when i delete this then it gives another error.